# Ajax call : sent boolean interpreted as string in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, types, boolean

I've noticed that a variable sent in an AJAX call (jQuery) as a type:boolean was interpreted as a type:string on the server side (PHP). Here is an extract of my code, to illustrate that:

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'model/script.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : ref,
    success : function (data){
       ...
    }
});
```

If I test the `ref` variable type in my JS script:

```
var ref_type = jQuery.type(ref);
alert(ref_type);
// Result : boolean
```

If I test the `$_POST['ref']` type in my PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['ref'])){
    echo gettype($_POST['ref']);
}
// Result : string
```

Is there a way to send / recept a boolean variable? Or do I have to cast the variable in the PHP script? I might have missed something...

Comment: You cannot send a Boolean, it is an HTTP request. You have to cast is in your PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular post request body (technically speaking, a `x-www-form-urlencoded` message) is nothing but text. Even numbers are text. Everything is text, because in the end this is what the browser sends and the server receives:

```
Name=John%20Smith&Age=35&Subscribed=true
```

Just pick a convention for true/false and make an explicit conversion in your server-side code:

```
switch ($_POST['ref']) {
    case 'yeah':
        $ref = true;
        break;
    case 'nope':
        $ref = false;
        break;
    default:
        $ref = null;
}
```

If you pick a value set that PHP will recognise correctly when [casting from string to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) the code can get simpler:

```
$ref = (bool)$_POST['ref'];
```

Or you can just let PHP do all the hard work:

```
$ref = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ref', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

Alternatively, you can use plain text to transmit a serialised complex data structure that supports complex data types and has encoder/decoder both in client and server platforms. A typical choice is JSON.

Comment: Thank you much for this clear explanation! I have eventually chosen to send `'yes`/ `'no'`string values to avoid casting on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the variable in your PHP code because the data is converted into (one) string and gets sent as it.